# How can I draw a dot on the screen on touchesEnded using UIBezierpath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

Can someone here please show me how to draw a single dot using UIBezierpath? I am able to draw a line using the UIBezierpath but if I remove my finger and put it back and then remove nothing get drawn on the screen.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
    [pPath moveToPoint:p];
    [pPath stroke];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
     [pPath stroke];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your path doesn't include any line or curve segments to be stroked.

Try this instead:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint p = [touches.anyObject locationInView:self];
    static CGFloat const kRadius = 3;
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(p.x - kRadius, p.y - kRadius, 2 * kRadius, 2 * kRadius);
    pPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:rect];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
    [pPath fill];
}
```

Comment: Hello @Rob can I start the path with a Oval?

Comment: @Ranjit Sure.  Why not?  You don't need my permission.

Comment: Ok , @robmayoff, can you look at this and suggest me how it can be done better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281278/draw-a-path-with-variable-width-in-ios

Answer (score 5):

I used this code:

```
 -(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)singleTap { 
     //draw dot on screen

     CGPoint tapPoint = [singleTap locationInView:self];
     [bezierPath_ moveToPoint:tapPoint];
     [bezierPath_ addLineToPoint:tapPoint];

     [self setNeedsDisplay]; 
}
```