# I am not able to delete single dot drawn from UIBezierpath Path

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibezierpath

I am using  UIBezierpath to draw a dot on my UIView.
I followed this link for the same.

[How can i draw a dot on the screen on touchesEnded using UIBezierpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844057/how-can-i-draw-a-dot-on-the-screen-on-touchesended-using-uibezierpath)

Now when I am done with this, I am able to add "dots" as much as I can. and adding these dots to an array and showing them on UIView.

If I clean the array on selection of eraser then all dots are getting cleared. I am not able to clear single/particular dot.

This is the method used for adding dots to an array and showing them on UIView.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [incrementalImage drawInRect:rect];
         for (int i = 0; arrayOfDots.count>i;i++)
         {
             UIBezierPath *path = [arrayOfDots objectAtIndex:i];
             UIColor *color = [arrayOfDotColor objectAtIndex:i];
             [color setFill];
             [path fill];
         }
}
```

I have eraser to clean the things drawn on UIView.
I am able to clean the lines drawn using UIBezierpath, but I am not able to clear the dot drawn using same UIBezierpath.

Eraser is nothing but, I am just picking the white colour and drawing the same white colour on my current view.

here is the code for eraser.

```
self.strockColour = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];

[objBezierpath setLineWidth:25];
```

Can any one guide me for the same on how to delete particular selected dot.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code fragment correctly, you are instantiating a new UIBezierPath object for every dot in the array.

So if you wish to erase a given dot, you will need the array of points to be mutable, and you would need to delete the actual path object from the array.

I suggest that you create a single UIBezierPath object and have an array that stores only the CGPoints.